# Save loop deleting one end of many-to-many CoreData relationship

Tags: core-data

I've been looking at this one for a while but can't seem to crack it. Its the first many-to-many relationship I have built in CoreData and obviously there is something simple I am missing...

I have a screen where I maintain two different Core Data 'entities', the entities are related via a many-to-many relationship. The first entity and the relationships between the first and second entity are maintained on the first tab of the screen and this seems to be working fine allowing me to delete the first entity instances and add/remove relationships between the first and second entities.

My problems are on the second tab where I maintain the second entity. They entities display fine and I can update their attributes, however, attempts to delete them results in a never-ending save loop.

I believe I have verified the loop by adding an NSLog entry into the willSave method of the second entity's NSManagedObject class.

The entities are displayed in NSTableViews backed by NSArrays (I haven't used binding).
I'm sharing the one managedObjectContext between the two tabs and the delete operation is simple (see below):

```
int currentRow = [[tableView selectedRowIndexes] firstIndex];
NSManagedObject *targetObject = [self.array objectAtIndex:currentRow];
NSError *error = nil;
[managedObjectContext deleteObject:targetObject];
if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
   NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
   abort();
}
```

Hopefully someone can help...

Regards

Scott

Comment: There's not a whole lot to go on here. Try posting some more info about your environment at the time the error occurs, if it is infinite looping use shark or the 'sample' command to get a trace. As a last resort, post your code in it's entirety.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so it ended up being simple (and my fault :)

I should have mentioned that the data I had been using had been loaded into the generated SQLite3 file using a separate data load script (I'm using data from a variety of sources).

There were some records I had added that did not contain a value for Z_OPT and CoreData was failing on delete of these records (then re-attempting the delete over and over).

Once I populated Z_OPT everything worked.
I think I'll be letting CoreData manage all changes to the database from now on :)

Thanks again to @TechZen and @ImHuntingWabbits for your responses.

Comment: Since the Core Data schema is undocumented, it is very dangerous to try and generate the SQLite stores directly. Getting it right is tricky and even if you do, Apple may change the schema without warning.

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot to go on here but check your delete rules.

If you have a many-to-many relationship set to `delete` on both sides, deleting one object can set off a cascade of deletes because deleting one object triggers the deletion of all its related objects which in turn delete all their related objects and so on.

If you've customized `willSave` or `willTurnIntoFault` or similar methods you may have introduced a loop in that code as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for your replies... Apologies for the lack of detail but I wasn't really seeing much from the app and the code (I think) is pretty standard.

Comment: thanks for your reply... Both sides of the relationship were set to Delete Rule: Nullify. Just then I tried making the 'entity 2' side Delete Rule: No Action but it hasn't helped. The only code added to willSave was the NSLog that proved it was getting into a loop I have now removed this. I'd love to provide some more information to you guys but am not sure how to get it... I tried the sample command mentioned by @ImHuntingWabbits (thanks also for your comment) but I can't really see what's causing the loop... What's the best way of posting the contents of that file?

Comment: OK so some more information on what is happening behind the scenes... I ran my app with the SQLDebug option and it shows that the delete is being rolled back then attempted again (log file date & time removed): CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: DELETE FROM ZSYMPTOM WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_PK,Z_OPT FROM ZSYMPTOM WHERE Z_PK IN (9) ORDER BY Z_PK
CoreData: annotation: sql execution time: 0.0012s CoreData: sql: ROLLBACK